# "NullPointerException when accessing methods of JwtTokenHelper in JwtAuthenticationFilter in Spring application"

Tags: java, jwt

["NullPointerException when accessing methods of JwtTokenHelper in JwtAuthenticationFilter in Spring application here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSX4W.png)

Encountering a NullPointerException when attempting to access methods of JwtTokenHelper within JwtAuthenticationFilter in a Spring application. Despite proper autowiring and bean configuration, the jwtTokenHelper object remains null when calling its methods, leading to the exception. This issue disrupts the JWT authentication flow and requires resolution to ensure proper functioning of the authentication mechanism. Seeking insights into potential causes and solutions to address this NullPointerException effectively.

Comment: Add all relevant information as text not as image